# Sending 15 records as api request in every one second absolutely with Java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to send multiple request to other api and update response status to our database every one second , let sending request is TPS = 15. I used both Timer and ScheduleExecutorService as below. But both did not support by sending 15 requests in every 1 second periodically. Sometimes it works well requests = 15 in every one second . And sometimes only requests = 13 in 11:04:01 and requests = 17 in 11:04:02. By seeing seconds, in 11:04:01 I want to send is 15 records, actually it sent 13 records, difference is 2 records. so, another 11:04:02 , remaining 2 records reached to this second and total records become 15+2 = 17 records. So, Please help me to solve this issue and which technology or library should I use rather than both Timer and ScheduledExecutorService.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new sendRequest(), 0, 1000);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor =
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    // Invoke method(s) to do the work
    doPeriodicWork();
}
};

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is attachment log file screenshot.
[mismatch and merge records in next second log screenshot in each second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShTNR.png)

Comment: I'm not confident that I completely understand your question, but you might find Guava's [`RateLimiter`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/25.1-jre/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) class useful.

Comment: Are you certain that your counted rate discrepancy is not caused by the time resolution of 1 second? E.g. if the scheduler happened to start at `11:02:56.889` and a rate of 15 transactions happens to take more than `1s - 0.889s`, you would see less (or more) records being produced if you only check at whole second clock intervals.

Comment: Is the goal to *send* 15 requests per second, for the remote service to *receive* 15 requests per second, or for your code to receive 15 *responses* per second? Those are all very different things. While the sending rate is mostly under your control (modulo other threads or processes on the same machine), the rate of responses depends on many other factors, including network latency and the latency of the remote service itself. 15 requests/second means that each request needs to take no more than 67 milliseconds, at the long tail of latency. What latency and throughput does the API support?

Comment: Thanks a lot all of your supporting answers. Issue can solve now by calculation time taken for one transaction instead of putting all 15 transactions in one second.

Comment: maxTPS = 15;Timer timer = new Timer(); int maxSleepInterval = Math.round((1000 / maxTPS));timer.schedule(new CurrentClassName(), 0, maxSleepInterval);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SendTPS extends TimerTask {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int maxTPS = 15;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    int maxSleepInterval = Math.round((1000 / maxTPS));

    timer.schedule(new SendTPS(), 0, maxSleepInterval);
  }

  public static  void fetchData(){
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new 
    java.util.Date())+"fetch data....");
  }

  public void run() {
    fetchData();
  }
}
```

Comment: Let TPS = 15. this app can send not to exceed TPS 15. But (1)if there is IO/Network overhead, it sends less than TPS15 in some seconds. In this case , in normal state,it can send TPS = 15 and in IO/Network overhead state, it can send less than TPS15 that is not exceed TPS = 15, TPS error will be solved.